# Meaning of be given to me

Tags: grammar

> ....I asked John for his resignation, which was given to me this morning. I thank John very much for his service. I will be naming a new National Security Advisor next week. [Twitter](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/1171452881729228802)

Hi, I'd like to know why President Trump said "was given to me". Didn't he make the decision by himself? What made him say "was given"?

Comment: The question is unclear as asked. Please describe the event as you understand it (the firing or resignation of Bolton), then ask your questions about the language in the Tweet. You ask "Didn't he make the decision by himself?" Didn't *who* make *what* decision? Your question is ambiguous.

Comment: *Be given to me* means Someone or something gives me something. I assume you actually know that, and it is not your actual question.

Comment: I thought “which” indicated the situation (President asked John for his resignation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### “was given”?

The phrase simply means that “John gave me his resignation” (John quit), in the passive voice.

### Who decided?

Your second question:

> Didn't he make the decision by himself?

is out of scope for ELL and can be better addressed at [Politics Stack Exchange.](http://politics.stackexchange.com)

Comment: But the first sentence says Trump asked John for his resignation. Then does it mean after the asking, John gave President his resignation?

Comment: @MangoGummy That depends on what you mean. *Somebody* actually delivered the message. How it was delivered or who delivered it isn't stated. However, the resignation at least *came from* John.